# Rails/Puma: Extremely slow view rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started with Ruby & Rails, and installed it via the RailsInstaller, currently I'm working on the Tutorial and Get Started section and single pages without any logic take 6000 ms (or more) to load. It's absolutely horrible. I tried `config.assets.debug = false` but that didn't help at all... I'm on Windows 10

Thanks!

Edit:

This line looks suspicious:

```
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (13516.0ms)
```

Comment: How's everything else on your machine. Have you looked at your Task Manager?

Comment: I'm starting the server through cmd and the process shows 0-1% CPU and <1 MB RAM. I've got 8 GB RAM and an i5...

Answer (score -1):

you are using: `rails s puma`? if your are doing that, check the console, maybe something with your assets is not right and is causing the delay. Rails use turbolinks in order to improve the call of assets.

Comment: Please copy and paste:

The output or your terminal, your routes file and in your terminal put this: rake routes and paste the results too.